# how to make two separate div holes working at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two separate holes that would show a portion of a background image but the rest would just be a giant white shadow, basically something like glasses.

But the problem is I can only get one hole at a time to work, if I just add one more it just covers the other one and I don't know how to fix it...

HTML

```
</head>
<body>
    <div  class="hole"></div>
    <div  class="hole1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.hole{
    left: 800px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    top: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.hole1{
    left: 950px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    top: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

body{
    background-image: url(/themes/img1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code does not show what you expect. Can you create a sample (image?).

Comment: Please make your code into a. runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think and possibly last resort is by creating 2 image, don't worry as it will only load the image once, you can check this through dev tools network tab. The code is messy but it will get the work done.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* must be position:relative; if you want absolute to be relative to this container */
.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
/* you can do position: absolute here then you can do top:0, left:0;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100% */
.img {
    background-image: url(/themes/img1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hole{
    left: 800px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    top: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hole1{
    left: 950px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    top: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Con: there are two class of dom img. Note: The browser(network) does not load the image twice. -->
        <div class="hole"><div class="img"/></div></div>
        <div class="hole1"><div class="img"/></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```